# Accessing object inside of object with 'for-in'?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a var set up as follows:

```
var player = {
    total: 150,
    upgrades: {
        item1: {
            cost: 100,
            id: "1",
        },
        item2: {
            cost: 200,
            id: "2",
        },
    },
}
```

I then have the following code, to try and use the data:

```
function checkUpgrades() {
    for(var x in player.upgrades)
    {
        if(player.total >= x.cost) {
            $("#"+x.id).prop("disabled","false");
        }
        else {
            $("#"+x.id).prop("disabled","true");
        }
    }
}
```

This is part of a loop that runs periodically, with the intention of enabling or disabling buttons accordingly. The issue I'm having is that while the for..in loop gets the item fine, 'x.id' and 'x.cost' return 'undefined'. I assume it's not retrieving the inner data, but I can't figure out why. Is there any method of doing this that might be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for-in loop iterate over all the prototype chain not only the properties of the object which is bad for performance [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in). You should use it with **hasOwnProperty()** [hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).

```
 function checkUpgrades() {
    for(var x in player.upgrades)
    {
        if (player.upgrades.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
           if(player.total >= player.upgrades[x].cost) {
               $("#"+x.id).prop("disabled","false");
           }
           else {
               $("#"+x.id).prop("disabled","true");
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Changing it to player.upgrades[x] worked perfectly, and thank you for telling me about that issue!

Comment: I do actually have another issue, if you might be able to help: `$("#"+player.upgrades[x].id).prop("disabled","false");` doesn't seem to be accessing anything, or at the very least not correctly enabling the button.

Comment: try $("#"+player.upgrades[x].id).attr("disabled","false")

Comment: Attr doesn't work either, oddly. It's able to retrieve the correct value - `console.log($("#"+player.upgrades[x].id).prop("disabled"));` returns true, it just isn't changing it to false.

Comment: Ok i made a search and some uses this $("#elementID").removeAttr('disabled').

Comment: The answer ended up being that I was stupid, and false should not have been in quotations. Whoops.

Comment: It is ok, i did not notice it too. It happens.

Answer (score 3):

Given a `for (x in something)` loop, `x` is the *name* of the property (i.e. the string `"item1"`), not the value (the object).

If you want to get to the value you need to explicitly access it (`something[x]`).

Comment: Changing in to of gave me an error saying that player.upgrades is not iterable. I also tried a `for(var i = 0; i < player.upgrades.length; i++)` loop, but it's returning the length as undefined.

Comment: @Makaires you can use Object.keys (and access on the key similar to the for..in) or Object.entries/values to get an iterable with the value already present.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```js
var player = {
  total: 150,
  upgrades: {
    item1: {
      cost: 100,
      id: "1",
    },
    item2: {
      cost: 200,
      id: "2",
    },
  },
}

function checkUpgrades() {
  for (var item in player.upgrades) {
    console.log(item); // items logs the property name

    // we can access the upgrades in the following manner:
    if (player.total >= player.upgrades[item].cost) {
      console.log('your code to be executed');
    }

  }
}


checkUpgrades();
```

### Important to realize:

1. In a `for in` loop >> `for el of element`, `el` will give the **property name** of the object **not the property value!**
2. We can use the property name using the `[]` operator which will dynamically assess a property. For example:

`myObj[myProp]`

Where myObj is an object and myProp a variable which will evaluate to a property name.